# Question without prior research

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

## Questão sem pesquisa prévia

**[pt]**
Eu escrevi está pergunta que é bem simples e assim como a maioria das perguntas feitas durante o *beta* são usadas para adicionar conteúdo ao site, no entanto alguns usuários parecem discordar, se valendo do argumento que eu não fiz uma pesquisa prévia.

**[en]**
I wrote is question (is very simple) and like most of the questions asked during the *beta* are used to add *content* to the site, however some users seem to disagree, taking advantage of the *argument* that **I did not do prior research**.

- [Which countries and regions speak Portuguese?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/148/8)

**[pt]**
No entanto eu já sei a resposta, mas eu apenas criei a pergunta com o motivo mesmo de ser uma fonte de pesquisa, sei que eu mesmo poderia ter respondido, mas várias perguntas feitas por mim e por outros colegas aqui no *beta* poderiam ter sido respondidas pelos próprios autores, mas o objetivo é também gerar participação também.

**[en]**
But I already know the answer, but I just created with the question why even be a source of research, I know that I myself might have answered.

But several questions asked by myself and other colleagues here in the "beta" could have been answered by the authors, but the goal is also there participation of the respondent.

I personally think it would be strange myself responding at this point.

### Minha opinião

Na minha opinião quase todas perguntas feitas aqui poderiam ser pesquisadas previamente, se for pra negativar ou fechar então que seja pelo motivo: *A pergunta não é sobre duvidas do idioma.*

### In my opnion

In my opinion almost all questions here could be researched in advance if it is to be downvote or close so that is the reason: *The question is not about language doubts.*

Comment: Pelo menos já começamos perceber quem são os usuários puristas, que gostam da regras pelas regras e não olham para o conteúdo e se ele é útil ou não para o site. O mesmo que está contra isto já argumentou comigo que o que importa é a regra, não o benefício ou malefício que trará ao site. Eu até acho que o momento não é agora para colocar qualquer tipo de pergunta mas nem vou entrar no mérito desta. O maior problema que eu vejo é o choque de culturas entre os usuários do SO/SE e do SOpt. Afinal a SE fez do SOpt um site completamente diferente do resto da rede.

Comment: This matter already has a meta post [here](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/34/should-we-try-to-populate-this-site-with-questions), but it's true that a consensus on whether to populate the site with questions or not was yet not established. I suggest we move this discussion to the other meta question.

Comment: @bigown é uma boa perspetiva a tua. A pergunta que fica é como resolveríamos este assunto. parece-me que vamos andar aqui eternamente as turras. Pelo que vejo todas as perguntas feitas neste site podem ser pesquisadas previamente, então não haveria conteúdo para o site.

Comment: @JorgeB. este é o meu pensamento, só não usei as mesmas palavras.

Comment: @JorgeB. exato, eu você sabe que eu acho que no SOpt fomos longe demais no que é permitido fazer, e por isso a qualidade baixou muito, ficou muito trabalho para comunidade ficar arrumando todos os problemas que as pessoas que perguntam causam. Mas aqui vemos que há usuários que querem o jeito mais SO, que é fechar tudo que pode sem se preocupar com o conteúdo de qualidade que é o que deveria reinar. Mas pra falar a verdade eu não me considero um membro da comunidade aqui, nem vou ficar discutindo o que vão fazer com este site.

Comment: @E_net4 I edited the question.

Comment: @bigown Concordo contigo, mas só pra ressaltar a minha discordancia com a atitude deles, se fosse pra seguir ao pé da letra o que é certo e errado aqui então as tags e perguntas deveriam ser em inglês.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu entendi perfeitamente.

Comment: They disagreed by downvoting (not close-voting), which means they think the question is not useful. There is no way to set rules for what people subjectively find useful. Also, do you want the "support" tag? I'm not clear why it's used here.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/22/15)

Comment: "Eu escrevi está pergunta que é" - Desculpe, mas o "está" deveria ser "esta", pois trata-se de um pronome, e não de um verbo. Na tradução para o inglês, o erro se reflete: "I wrote is question" ao invés de "I wrote this question".

Comment: @VictorStafusa sou apenas um entusiasta/aprendiz, se encontrar um erro pode editar :) - Sou ruim no inglês no português ainda, mas obrigado pela orientação!

Answer (score 3):

Todas as dúvidas sobre a nossa língua se encontram no google. Até porque toda a gente sabe um bocado da sua própria língua. No caso da programação é diferente. É mais restrito e há pouco conteúdo em Português até porque os programadores na sua maioria está habituado ao Inglês.

Mas afinal que perguntas se enquadrariam no site que uma pesquisa não respondesse primeiro?

Comment: Concordo, acho que se for pra negativar ou fechar que seja pelo motivo: *Está pergunta não é sobre gramatica/ortografia e ou pronuncia.* - Poderia colocar a resposta e Inglês também... Me parece que as pessoas que negativaram não usam o portugues nativamente, talvez seja um pouco dificil de "entender" pra eles :)

Comment: Aí vai ter a tal briga entre os que querem conteúdo e os que querem barrar conteúdo. E o meio-termo que seria ideal fica prejudicado. @GuilhermeNascimento eu acho que o problema é da cultura estabelecida no SO. Que nós achamos ruim. Eles provavelmente vão odiar a cultura do SOpt que pregamos. Como conciliar as duas? A SE arrumou um belo problema para resolver. Cada site você tem que ficar adaptando o modo de pensar. Eu acho que a do SO nem é mais usada de fato, mas algumas pessoas ainda agem como se quase qualquer conteúdo fosse indesejável. Falta a cultura do "que problema isso causa?".

Comment: @bigown isso acontece sempre, todos os *.SE são diferentes à sua maneira; ou não? ((Por exemplo, no codereview é normal e saudável haver *muitas* respostas diferentes, embora no SO não. Não porque a pergunta é subjetiva ou sobre opiniões (seria fechada, como o seria no SO), mas porque há muitas maneiras de melhorar o código, e muitas partes diferentes a melhorar, etc.)) Acho que temos de procurar o espírito deste nosso pt.SE, defini-lo enquanto comunidade, e *então* segui-lo. E não acho que falte a cultura do "que problemas isto pode causar?", nem a mim nem a ti. (Estou a escrever 1 resposta.)

Comment: Não queiramos também desprezar perguntas de especialistas, certo?

Answer (score 3):

O que diz no voto para baixo é `This question (1)does not show any research effort; it is (2)unclear or (3)not useful`. Eu achei que era (2)clara e (3)útil. Mas não achei que (1)mostrasse esforço de pesquisa, e então votei para baixo.

O que eu esperava era ou alguma tentativa indicada no corpo da pergunta, ou uma resposta colocada pelo autor.
Não encontrei, então achei que era uma questão de baixa qualidade, por ser uma pergunta de tipo "vampiro de ajuda".

---

Agora fui ler sobre vampiros de ajuda para expor o meu ponto de maneira sólida.
Encontrei isto: [The Help Vampire problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)

... e não pude deixar de concordar com a resposta topo.
Tive de mudar de opinião para: no fundo, as "perguntas-vampiro" não têm problema nenhum, *se forem de boa qualidade*.

Sendo o objetivo do StackExchange ser um repositório de respostas, parece-me que *qualquer* pergunta é boa se estiver no âmbito e se não for repetida.

## tl;dr

Se uma pergunta é clara, útil, objetiva, e contida... é uma boa pergunta.
E aquela é.

O esforço de resposta deve ser irrelevante.

Comment: A segunda parte começa ir pelo caminho certo. O resto é a regra pela regra, sem buscar um objetivo. Outra coisa que eu acho que é bom observar é que se você pode consertar o problema da pergunta, conserte ao invés de chutá-la. O importante é ter conteúdo de qualidade, o resto é secundário.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e obrigado por tentar ver ambos lados, sobre isto *ou uma resposta colocada pelo autor.*, sei que você entendeu, mas só pra ressaltar acredito que eu tenha me justificado, o motivo é dar a oportunidade de outras pessoas responderem, pois quase todas perguntas que formulei basicamente eu sabia a resposta. Poderia me dar uma dica mais clara de como melhorar a pergunta?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não, a pergunta está ótima. :) Já nem sequer tem -1. Antes de mudar de opinião, diria que poderia ter auto-respondido. (A não-resposta foi de propósito, percebo isso; mas a qualidade que vemos hoje é a qualidade que criamos amanhã, e eu gostava de ter uma comunidade com qualidade, por isso o meu voto não mudaria por perceber as razões por trás da ação, só se a minha perceção da ação mudasse. Bla bla bla.)

Comment: @bigown as regras são as regras; se não concordamos com elas podemos ou propor melhorá-las ou aceitá-las. Ignorá-las quando nos convém não me parece uma opção construtiva.

Comment: Não é ignorar a regra, é só olhar pra ela analisando o contexto. Usar a regra só porque é a regra é um problema enorme. Isso não ajuda absolutamente ninguém. Você está querendo ignorar uma regra maior que é construir um repositório de qualidade. Aplicar as regras cegamente não contribui para isto, apenas bloqueia que isto aconteça.

Comment: `Você está completamente errado porque eu penso diferente. Abra seus olhos!` Não vou discutir com argumentos destes, @bigown .

Comment: @ANeves eu sei que você pensa assim, você não tem argumentos, só olha para a regras como se elas fossem tudo. Por sorte tem outras pessoas que olham para o conteúdo.

Comment: Acho que é exatamente a fronteira do julgamento individual e onde consensos são formados, oficiais ou não. Por exemplo, se eu acho que (2) e (3) são interessantes até voto +1, mesmo não tendo esforço de pesquisa.