# Estamos abertos a qualquer tipo de pergunta que verse sobre a língua portuguesa?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

Meu questionamento tem a ver com [essa pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/teria-uai-alguma-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-o-ingl%C3%AAs-why) e pela reação de alguns colegas ao meu "closevote". Talvez para os colegas de além-mar a pergunta nada tenha de extraordinário uma vez que as palavras "uai" e "why" são ambas interjeições e tem pronuncia semelhante, além do fato de que esse falar mineiro é desconhecido em Portugal (e até em alguns estados do Brasil).

Mas, do lado de cá do Atlântico, qualquer professor de língua inglesa ou portuguesa reconhece logo o absurdo de se achar que uma palavra possa ter relação com a outra. "uai", interjeição usada pelo "mineirinho do interior" não é de uso corrente nas grandes cidades. Tem sua origem na fala do caipira, dos habitantes da roça. E eventualmente chega a alguns habitantes de Belo Horizonte. Mas é só isso.

E é sempre motivo de risos quando professores de Inglês explicam aos alunos o significado de "why" como interjeição e acrescentam em tom jocoso "It's influence from Minas Gerais", e todos riem. O absurdo de achar que possa haver alguma relação entre as duas palavras é tão grande quanto achar que a dança "forró", típica de alguns estados do nordeste do Brasil, tenha tido sua origem na expressão da língua inglesa "for all", significando que a dança seria para todos. Brinca-se muito por aqui com essas duas possibilidades que sabemos serem apenas falácias. E por aí vai, com muitas outras.

**REPITO AQUI A POSIÇÃO DO PROFESSOR MARIO EDUARDO VIARO**, professor da USP, doutor em Lingua Portuguesa, em relação a falácia do "uai" x "why": **Presença inglesa em Minas Gerais? Quando? Onde?** Mesmo que houvesse (suponhamos, na criação da malha ferroviária do interior), essa presença seria tão influente assim? **O que move a “teoria” desse leitor é a semelhança fonética. Isso é o mesmo que nada. Com base em duas ou três palavras é possível que imaginemos que qualquer língua do planeta tenha influência sobre outra. Já fizeram isso com o tupi e o japonês, com o quíchua e o húngaro. Em persa, “mau” se diz bad, como em inglês; em malaio mati é “olho”, como em grego moderno. E daí? Coincidência.** E mais: por que só essas palavras sobraram, se houve esse suposto contato? [(**referência e link**)](http://www.recantodasletras.com.br/humor/3790744)

Respeito quem formulou a pergunta mas é a minha opinião que perguntas desse tipo não enriquecem o site. Precisamos de mais perguntas para sairmos de beta, é verdade, mas precisamos de boas perguntas, ou no mínimo razoáveis. Sim, concordo que devemos ser mais complacentes com aqueles que estão ainda aprendendo o português como uma segunda língua.

Quanto ao comentário feito por um grande colaborador do site de que "só o fato de podermos encontrar a resposta através do Google não é motivo para se rejeitar uma pergunta." ou "Afinal, podemos encontrar tudo na Internet" eu respondo que há que haver um mínimo de pesquisa, e se a resposta pode ser facilmente encontrada em um dicionário, de etimologia ou não, definitivamente a pergunta será um mau exemplo e passaremos a receber esse tipo de pergunta: "qual a origem da palavra pedra?", "a palavra mesquinho teve sua origem em meskeen que significa pobre em árabe?  Se a pergunta não acrescenta nenhuma justificativa para essa suspeita, além da semelhança fonética, não pode ser considerada uma pergunta séria.  São perguntas semelhantes ao "uai" e não poderemos ter dois pesos e duas medidas. Deixo aberto a discussão pela comunidade.

Comment: +1 por colocar a questão no meta.

Comment: Estate no Google out não, imo, é irrelevante pq o Google indexa qualquer coisa que qualquer um postar. Alguém diz que o sol é frio pq quando subimos uma montanha e nos aproximamos dele fica mais frio e está no google.

Comment: Li os argumentos mas não quis participar antes. Agora no meta faz mais sentido. Eu já tive um comentário apagado pela moderação justamente por questionar a importância da pergunta, para a qual havia muitas referências na web. É importante esclarecer isso. Em outras comunidades (stackoverflow, por exemplo) se é "malhado" por postar uma pergunta cuja resposta já se encontre disponível com uma rápida pesquisa no Google, tenha ela valor científico ou não. Digo isso baseado na minha experiência.

Comment: Fui eu que disse, e mantenho, que «ser possível encontrar resposta na net nunca foi razão para fechar uma pergunta aqui». Concordo que é pergunta fraca aquela que é possível responder consultando um dicionário conceituado online. Mas isto **não é o caso** da pergunta sobre o *uai*: o [site indicado pelo Centaurus](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/palavras/uai/) sobre a origem de *uai* simplesmente publica respostas dos usuários sem qualquer controle de qualidade; neste caso, quatro respostas diferentes, sem fontes credíveis; e uma delas é precisamente que *uai* vem de *why*.

Comment: E não me consegui conter. Desde quando é que tu achas que perguntas cuja resposta se encontra facilmente num dicionário online deveriam ser desencorajadas? Tu defendeste veementemente [esta pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/o-que-seria-morfar-uma-sandes) que se responde facilmente com duas consultas ao [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/).

Comment: @Jacinto  Não, não defendi veementemente a pergunta. Eu apenas a formulei. Naquela época, eu frequentava o site há dois meses e  consultei apenas o meu Aurélio, que considero o melhor dicionário da língua portuguesa mas não encontrei as palavras,"morfar" e "sandes". Com o tempo descobri os dicionários de língua portuguesa online e passei a consultá-los também."Morfar uma sandes" é um termo desconhecido no Brasil.  Uma pergunta desse tipo contribui para ampliar a nossa cultura sobre pt-PT. Obtive uma excelente resposta que lá está postada e acessível a todos os brasileiros que visitam o site.

Comment: @eightShirt   Concordo plenamente.  Frequento um outro site do SE há alguns anos.  Lá recebemos mais de 100 perguntas em determinados dias da semana e, muitas são fechadas imediatamente pelos moderadores por não seguirem o padrão ditado pelos "powers-that-be".

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer, Jacinto. @Centaurus não formularei resposta porque não espero uma resposta definitiva desta questão, mas uma boa discussão. Sobre a pergunta do título, eu diria "não". Eu espero que a pergunta traga alguma contribuição, e concordo que há de haver um mínimo de pesquisa. Eu não aceitaria "Qual é o plural de casa?", por exemplo. Não estou comparando a questão que gerou o debate com esta que usei de exemplo, falo de uma forma geral. Li todos os comentários sem muita atenção, mas acho que ninguém respondeu sobre a pergunta do título, e sim com foco na pergunta sobre uai.

Comment: @eightShirt no StackOverflow em Português isso não acontece.

Comment: @Centaurus os argumentos que usas a favor da tua questão são os mesmos que deverias usar em favor desta. Eu nem sabia da existência desse uai. Posso argumentar da mesma forma. Além do mais, esta pergunta pode ser tudo menos fácil de encontrar resposta seja onde for, pelo menos na minha opinião.

Comment: Além disso acho que devíamos ter no site todo o tipo de perguntas que possa enriquecer o site no sentido de que haverá muita gente a pesquisar sobre o assunto e vai ajudar essas pessoas.

Comment: @JorgeB.   Parece que tu não entendeste a minha crítica à pergunta.  Acho válido e interessante que tenhamos uma pergunta sobre o "uai" de Minas Gerais: é um regionalismo e é interessante saber que tipo de falante usa a expressão, quando usa, onde é mais frequente, algumas frases com exemplos, etc.  Mas comparar "uai" com o "why" da língua inglêsa é o mesmo que dizer que "forró" surgiu com a presença de americanos do norte em Fortaleza, onde diziam que a dança era "for all".  Essa é a minha crítica.

Comment: Embora o OP não tenha tido essa intenção, não é uma pergunta séria para quem é brasileiro, conhece tanto o "uai" e o "why" e já cansou de brincar com a semelhança.  Tivesse a pergunta sido formulada de forma diferente, sem a comparação, até eu mesmo me interessasse em responder.   Entendo que para ti e para todos os colegas portugueses não haja nada de anormal na pergunta.  Mas também espero que tu tentes ver as coisas pelo meu ângulo de falante do pt-BR.  Não estou pedindo para que a pergunta seja fechada.

Comment: Quanto a não ser fácil encontrar uma resposta,  se tu pesquisares a etimologia de ambas as palavras separadamente, encontrarás a resposta.  Uma provém do Latim e a outra do Anglo-Saxon.

Comment: Esta questão tem vários tópicos que merecem discussão em separado... Assim em conjunto, polui a discussão.

Comment: @Centaurus os SE mais técnicos tem regras mais restritas sobre o que constitui uma boa pergunta. E moderadores pecam demais pelo excesso de zelo (que acaba sendo subjetivo).

Comment: @Mindwin Obrigado.  Já percebi.

Comment: Eu quero saber porque nenhum brasileiro (ou português) possa imaginar que em português exista: ai....ai para exprimir uma pena. Ai, que pena. uai: (exprime espanto, surpresa, impaciência, susto, terror). Também existe ué. Não poderia ser que o uai vem de uma espécie de amalgamacão ao interior da língua sem nenhuma refêrencia ao inglês?? O termo até poderia-se encontrar dentro da casa, e não pelo lado de fora.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Concordo plenamente com o @Jacinto de que "não devemos aceitar uma pergunta simplesmente por ter a ver com língua portuguesa"**

Contudo, sinto-me na obrigação de tecer alguns comentários quanto a cinco ítens de sua resposta, assim enumerados abaixo:

> - 1. "O trabalho trazido à nossa atenção que analisa a fundo a origem de uai — esta tese de mestrado citada na resposta do Eduardo à pergunta do uai — concluiu que a hipótese da origem em why é plausível. (Eu li a parte relevante da tese.) Ninguém disponibilizou nada que me faça desconsiderar essa tese."

A tese de mestrado em questão não faz uma análise da origem em "why" especificamente. **Quem seguir o  link e ler a referida cópia da tese, verá que essa origem é uma das doze possíveis origens cogitadas por seu autor**. E, nas conclusões, o autor da monografia afirma que:

*"os fatos e interpretações apresentados nesta dissertação poderão, certamente, ser interpretados à luz dos estudos de gramaticalização. Essa tarefa, entretanto, ficará aqui como uma sugestão de pesquisa, a ser realizada em um outro momento. **Outra tarefa deixada em aberto diz respeito à investigação da hipótese de empréstimo**."*

> - 2. "Ora se professores consideraram que a hipótese da origem em why tem mérito para ser investigada numa tese mestrado na Universidade Federal de Minas Gerais."

Foi uma das hipóteses, entre muitas outras.  **Também foi estudada a possibilidade do "uai" ter origem no alemão, no espanhol, no italiano, no japonês, no português e em dialetos indígenas, sem que o autor chegasse a conclusão alguma.**

> - 3. Para fundamentar o fecho da pergunta, o Centaurus indicou-nos este “consultório etimológico” num comentário à pergunta do uai, e o recanto de letras num comentário a esta minha resposta.

Eu forneci dois links nos comentários à sua resposta.  Um deles, o [**Oxford Dictionary Online**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/why) traz a etimologia de "why" (germânica).  O outro, [**O Recanto das Letras**](http://www.recantodasletras.com.br/humor/3790744), que embora não tenha sido criado por autoridades no assunto, exibe a cópia de um extenso artigo escrito por dois professores da USP, um deles o renomado professor Mário Eduardo Viaro, e publicado na revista Língua Portuguesa. **Nesse artigo o professor diz o seguinte quanto ao empréstimo linguístico referente ao "uai"**

> **Presença inglesa em Minas Gerais? Quando? Onde?** Mesmo que houvesse (suponhamos, na criação da malha ferroviária do interior), essa presença seria tão influente assim? ***O que move a “teoria” desse leitor é a semelhança fonética. Isso é o mesmo que nada.* Com base em duas ou três palavras é possível que imaginemos que qualquer língua do planeta tenha influência sobre outra.
>   Já fizeram isso com o tupi e o japonês, com o quíchua e o húngaro. Em persa, “mau” se diz bad, como em inglês; em malaio mati é “olho”, como em grego moderno. E daí? Coincidência.** E mais: por que só essas palavras sobraram, se houve esse suposto contato?

O professor [**Mário Eduardo Viaro**](http://dlcv.fflch.usp.br/node/163), professor da Universidade de São Paulo, é doutor em língua portuguesa, e autor de vários livros inclusive o [**"Manual de Etimologia do Português"**](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Por_tr%C3%A1s_das_palavras.html?hl=pt-BR&id=sq4C403IwWIC)

> - 4. "Pode ser que um usuário não conheça nenhum dicionário online, e poste uma pergunta sem indicar qualquer pesquisa prévia. Nesse caso, poderíamos num comentário chamar a atenção para estes dicionários e pedir ao usuário que os consultasse e revisse a pergunta; e fechá-la se ele não o fizesse."

**Concordo plenamente, exceto  em se tratando de perguntas ridículas do tipo "Forró tem origem em for all?"** ("forró x for all" e "uai x why" são duas das falácias etimológicas mais comuns neste lado do Atlântico)  Essas, eu sempre votarei pelo fechamento. E respeito o voto de outros que pensem o contrário, assim como espero que respeitem o meu. **O fato de eu, ou alguém, dar um voto para fechamento de uma pergunta não significa que esteja pedindo para que outros o façam.** Pela reação de alguns, parece que interpretaram dessa forma.

> - 5. "Eu posso indicar várias perguntas aqui do site, incluindo algumas da autoria do Centaurus, que demonstram muito menos pesquisa prévia que a pergunta do uai"

**O problema não foi tanto a falta de pesquisa, que realmente foi mínima. O problema foi a pergunta em si** que muitos por aqui no Brasil consideram ridícula. Sim, consideram ridícula porque já foi até alvo de piada até em programas de televisão. Não quis usar a palavra "ridícula", na página referente à pergunta, em respeito a quem a postou, mas teus argumentos me obrigam a usá-la agora. Muitas perguntas que não demonstram nenhum esforço de pesquisa prévia são altamente interessantes e informativas. Eu poderia citar algumas que foram formuladas aqui.  Nem toda pergunta precisa de uma pesquisa prévia e, em certos casos é até impossível fazê-la. Mas, certamente, toda pergunta deve conter o máximo de informação possível sobre aquilo que o OP já sabe e sobre suas dúvidas.

**Nunca emiti um voto para que uma pergunta fosse fechada e essa foi a primeira vez. Ao encontrar novamente uma pergunta que eu pense não contribuir para o acervo do site, novamente votarei pelo seu fechamento.** Não sou moderador, não pretendo sê-lo, e há democracia no site: exceto pelos moderadores, estes com um único voto, somente cinco votos podem fechar uma pergunta.

Answer (score 8):

Julgar perguntas que enriquecem ou não o site com base em opiniões pessoais só leva à discriminação. A origem do uai é mais relevante, imo, do que a origem de malhação e eu não vi ninguém se opor àquela pergunta.

Estar no google não quer dizer nada. Qualquer coisa está no google. A internet é a maior lixeira do mundo.

Imo, esta página só tem sentido pq as pessoas têm dificuldade em separar o joio do trigo e perceber o que é que está no google e é verdadeiro.

Se eu coloco uma pergunta no google e percebo muito claramente a resposta correta, ela não deveria estar aqui. Critérios tipo uai não é IN o suficiente e não é mais usada acabam por ser meio achismo.

Julgar com base na facilidade da resposta é muito mais justo como critério.

Apesar de eu achar a origem do uai inútil e pouco relevante, não o é para quem fez a pergunta. Por isso mesmo respondi.

Um site como este não pode ser baseado no que (eu/tu/ele) acho mas sobre critérios claros.

Comment: Concordo que seja interessante pesquisar a origem do "uai".  Só não acho interessante comparar com o "why" saxônico com o "uai" mineirês.

Comment: Não se trata de julgar as perguntas com base em opiniões pessoais.  O SE tem regras claras sobre o que deve ser aceito.  Não devem ser aceitas perguntas que solicitem listas, perguntas cujas respostas sejam baseadas em opiniões, perguntas que não sejam claras, perguntas cujas respostas sejam facilmente encontradas em dicionários.  Encoraja-se perguntas bem formuladas.

Comment: Por exemplo: ""pesquisei a etimologia de "why" e encontrei "isso e isso".  Pesquisei também a etimologia de "uai" e encontrei "isso".  Por esses motivos me parece que as duas palavras tem uma origem comum.""  Isso seria uma pergunta adequada.

Comment: @Centaurus inevitavelmente, essa comparação iria surgir, se não fosse na pergunta, na resposta. Eu já entendi o seu mal estar com essa comparação, mas isso não pode ser motivo para a pergunta ser ou não off-topic.

Comment: @Centaurus Desde quando é que etimologia das palavras é off-topic? Não é a mesma coisa que ver no dicionário, basta ver pela sua pesquisa que foi parar a sites que eu nem conheço.

Comment: @JorgeB.  Na tua resposta, o comentário sobre "qual a origem da palavra pedra?" foi outro.

Comment: @Centaurus onde está isso?

Comment: @JorgeB.   " Não me parece que esteja dentro dos exemplos que enunciaste. Esses exemplos, para mim, também estariam fechados."

Comment: @Centaurus ah sim esses sim. Mas como eu disse, acho que esse não está dentro desse tipo de exemplo.

Comment: "Um site como este não pode ser baseado no que (eu/tu/ele) acho mas sobre critérios claros."    Claro !!!   Mas esses critéiros existem e não vi ninguém postá-los em uma resposta.

Comment: Já agora, aonde? A sério, não estou brincando, procurei aqui e não encontrei. Confesso que é melhor que eu leia antes de falar mais alguma coisa...

Comment: @EduardoFernandes  quando votamos para que uma pergunta seja colocada "on hold" ou que seja "fechada", surgem as 5 possibilidades pelas quais uma pergunta pode ser fechada.   Mas os moderadores podem responder melhor do que eu e transmitir aquilo que os "powers-that-be", (conforme são chamados aqueles que controlam o site) ditam como regras básicas para a aceitação de uma pergunta ou não.

Comment: É que "onde não há lei, não há transgressão". Se não é claro o que pode ou não, a própria pergunta é sem sentido. A pergunta deveria ser, as regras são estas. Devemos adicionar alguma limitação a elas?

Comment: @EduardoFernandes   Não cabe a mim dizer para os outros membros do site o que pode ou o que não pode.  Cabe aos moderadores.  A mim cabe o que fiz: ao achar que uma pergunta não se enquadra nos critérios estabelecidos pelo SE (frequento outros sites do SE e eles tem critérios mais ou menos homogêneos) utilizar o meu voto.  Uma vez que recebi uma crítica por fazê-lo, trouxe a discussão para o meta.  Mas o que se discutiu aqui até agora foi a pergunta a qual dei o "closevote" e os moderadores pouco esclareceram o que eu esperava.

Comment: Eu percebo-te, na boa... Mas estou a dar minha opinião: se eu não souber mais nenhum critério, só me basearia na facilidade de encontrar ou não uma resposta sem postar aqui para perceber se uma pergunta é ou não válida.

Comment: @Centaurus o que é on-topic ou off-topic não é só o que vem nas regras do site, a comunidade é que decide muitas dessas coisas. Se uma pergunta for claramente off-topic eu mesmo a fecho, se for um caso como este em que há discórdia da comunidade, eu deixo a comunidade decidir. Em último caso pode-se chamar um CM para ver o assunto.

Comment: @JorgeB.   Você poderia então postar uma resposta citando o que são as regras do site?  Muitos membros não as conhecem.

Answer (score 5):

Centaurus, o que eu quis dizer é que o facto de estar no google não é motivo suficiente para fechar uma pergunta.

O facto de a pergunta poder parecer ridícula, não quer dizer que ela seja, há muita gente que não sabe a resposta. E só por ai já me aprece mais que adequada ao site. Não me parece que esteja dentro dos exemplos que enunciaste. Esses exemplos, para mim, também estariam fechados.

Por exemplo, a pergunta [É correto eu dizer "eu vou ir" em português?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/270/153), aqui em Portugal diriam o mesmo que disseste, que os professores iriam rir e que é errado dizer isso, mas a verdade é que "Eu vou ir" é completamente correto e gramatical.

Comment: Ainda reparei agora que há uma resposta baseada na tese de uma pessoa, não será um indicio que a pergunta é bem pertinente?

Comment: Jorge, a diferença é que a pergunta "uai x why" já saturou a paciência de quem é falante da língua inglesa no Brasil.  No início tinha até graça, mas atualmente...   Quanto a "resposta baseada na tese de uma pessoa" precisamos ver de quem se trata.  Algum professor de linguística da USP ou da UNICAMP. etc. fez uma pesquisa a respeito ?   Estou interessado em saber.

Comment: @Centaurus mas isso não são razões para que a pergunta não seja valida no site.

Comment: Sim, mas o fato de existirem dicionários de etimologia online, até bons dicionários, é um motivo.  O SE desencoraja (ou pelo menos desencorajava)  a aceitação de perguntas que demonstrem falta de pesquisa prévia quando ela é disponível, ou cujas respostas sejam facilmente encontradas em qualquer dicionário.  A resposta a pergunta em questão é facilmente encontrada em dicionários de etimologia.

Comment: @Centaurus então podemos fechar a maioria das perguntas de etimologia. É um assunto que tem de ser revisto, se quiseres fazer uma pergunta sobre isso no meta. Já que temos um grande número desse tipo de pergunta de etimologia X vs Y e mesmo de etimologia de uma palavra só.

Comment: Não digo que as perguntas sobre etimologia devam ser fechadas, mas elas devem conter alguma informação sobre pesquisa prévia.  Uma pergunta do tipo "a palavra "fodder" da lingua inglesa tem alguma relação com a palavra "foder" do português?"  tem que fornecer algum motivo para ter sido formulada além do fato de as duas palavras terem grafia semelhante.  Da mesma forma "qual a origem de mentecapto?"  A pergunta não pode ser apenas isso.  Caso contrário eu poderia formular 500 perguntas por dia e isso não traria nenhum beneficio à qualidade do site.

Comment: Da mesma forma, perguntas que são apenas uma tentativa de fazer humor, devem ser desencorajadas. (com closevotes)  Por exemplo:  A palavra forró teve sua origem no "for all" da língua inglesa?   Existem muitas perguntas desse tipo aqui no Brasil porque boatos sem qualquer base sólida correm a solta.  "sem qualquer base sólida" foi um pleonasmo, acho.

Comment: @Centaurus então não achas que [Teria “uai” alguma relação com o inglês “why”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3650/153) não demonstra esforço de pesquisa? A mim parece-me que sim, tem fontes e tudo. Acho que ninguém está na comédia, acho que o AP tem mesmo essa dúvida. Acho que estás a levar demasiado "a peito" esse tipo de perguntas de boatos, e a exagerar com essa pergunta. Eu já te dei o exemplo do "eu vou ir" que também é feita de boatos como essa.

Answer (score 2):

A resposta à pergunta no título é não. Não devemos aceitar uma pergunta simplesmente por ter a ver com língua portuguesa: eu votaria para fechar um pergunta sobre a origem de *pedra* ou sobre o plural de *casa*. E já apareceram aqui no site várias perguntas relacionadas com a língua portuguesa que nós fechamos. Agora, isto não é o cerne da questão, até porque já existem sobre este assunto [esta pergunta sobre questões sem pesquisa prévia](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/question-without-prior-research) e mais [esta sobre questões superficiais](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/sobre-quest%C3%B5es-superficiais).

O cerne desta pergunta, exposto no corpo, é a aceitabilidade da  [pergunta sobre a possível relação entre *uai* e *why*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/teria-uai-alguma-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-o-ingl%C3%AAs-why). A meu ver foram apresentados dois argumentos para a fechar, e nenhum deles me convence:

1. Que os professores de inglês e português no Brasil sabem que a origem de *uai* no inglês *why* é um disparate sem fundamento;
2. E que a pergunta do *uai* não demonstra pesquisa prévia e pode ser facilmente respondida mediante consulta a um dicionário.

### 1º argumento — os professores sabem que aquilo é um disparate

Eu não estou nas melhores condições para avaliar o que sabem os professores no Brasil. Mas se é verdade que eles sabem que a questão do *uai* – *why* é um disparate, não deveria ser difícil apresentar provas disso. E até agora eu ainda não as vi, apesar de ter lido com atenção tudo o que foi escrito aqui no site sobre o assunto: a pergunta do *uai*, sua resposta e comentários; a pergunta aqui no meta, as duas respostas e os 49 comentários existentes até agora.

O trabalho trazido à nossa atenção que estuda a fundo a origem de *uai* — [esta tese de mestrado](http://www.bibliotecadigital.ufmg.br/dspace/bitstream/handle/1843/BUOS-9BVJCP/uai_estudo_de_uma_interjei__o_do_portugu_s_brasileiro_2013.pdf?sequence=1) citada na [resposta do Eduardo à pergunta do *uai*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/teria-uai-alguma-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-o-ingl%C3%AAs-why/3654#3654) — analisa a hipótese da origem em *why* (p. 83-92) e concluiu que ela é plausível (p. 108). Analisam nove outras hipóteses, das quais, oito rejeitam e uma consideram também plausível. (Eu li a parte relevante da tese.) Ninguém disponibilizou nada que me faça desconsiderar essa tese.

Ora se professores consideraram que a hipótese da origem em *why* tem mérito para ser investigada numa tese mestrado na Universidade Federal de Minas Gerais, vamos ser nós que vamos dizer que ela não tem mérito para ser objeto de uma pergunta no nosso site? E se vários outros professores aprovaram a tese, com a conclusão da plausibilidade da origem em *why*, eu fico com dúvidas acerca de ‘os professores sabem que a ligação *uai*–*why* é um disparate’; dúvidas suficientes para não querer fechar a pergunta com base nesse argumento.

### 2º argumento — falta de pesquisa prévia e resposta nos dicionários

Este argumento não tem fundamento. Poderíamos argumentar que perguntas que tenham resposta direta num qualquer dicionário conceituado online deveriam ser fechadas. Ora eu conheço o [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Default.aspx), [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/index.php), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/), [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/) e a [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/); consultei-os e em nenhum deles se encontra resposta à pergunta do *uai*.

Para fundamentar o fecho da pergunta, o Centaurus indicou-nos [este “consultório etimológico”](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/palavras/uai/) num comentário à pergunta do *aui*, e o [*recanto de letras*](http://www.recantodasletras.com.br/humor/3790744) num comentário a esta minha resposta. Não vou argumentar aqui se podemos ou não encontrar nestes sites resposta à pergunta do *uai*. O relevante para mim é que estes sites não são suficientemente conhecidos, pelo que não podemos exigir que um usuário os consulte e incorpore na sua pergunta.

Poderíamos exigir que consulte um dicionário bem conhecido e reputado. Pode ser que um usuário não conheça nenhum dicionário online, e poste uma pergunta sem indicar qualquer pesquisa prévia. Nesse caso, poderíamos num comentário chamar a atenção para estes dicionários e pedir ao usuário que os consultasse e revisse a pergunta; e fechá-la se ele não o fizesse. Mas se nós encontrarmos resposta à pergunta em sites relativamente desconhecidos, então o que devemos fazer é citá-los e responder à pergunta com base neles. Não devemos fechar a pergunta. Reunir a informação desses sites pouco conhecidos num resposta tem utilidade e valoriza o nosso site.

### Conclusão

Não é nada claro que qualquer professor de inglês ou português no Brasil saiba que a ligação *uai* – *why* é absurda; e a pergunta do *uai* não tem resposta numa consulta direta a dicionários online que eu conheça. Por isso votei para manter a pergunta aberta.

Quanto a fechar perguntas com resposta direta em dicionários online, eu fui muito cauteloso, dizendo apenas que poderíamos fazê-lo. A razão dessa cautela é que nós não temos até agora adotado essa norma. E não devemos ter dois pesos e duas medidas. Eu posso indicar várias perguntas aqui do site, incluindo algumas da autoria do Centaurus, que demonstram muito menos pesquisa prévia que a pergunta do *uai*; e cujas respostas se podem encontrar diretamente no Priberam ou procurando uma ou duas palavras-chave no Google. Portanto deveríamos ponderar com cuidado se queremos passar a seguir critérios mais exigentes.

Comment: "Que é do conhecimento geral no Brasil que a origem de uai no inglês why é um disparate..."  Desculpe-me Jacinto, mas eu não fiz tal afirmação.  Mesmo porque talvez 50% dos brasileiros nem conheçam a palavra "why".  ´Minha afirmação foi a de que qualquer professor de língua inglesa ou portuguesa reconhece logo o absurdo de se achar que uma palavra possa ter relação com a outra.

Comment: "Eu procurei em vários, e não encontrei nada que rejeitasse a origem em why."  não encontraste porque não existe.  Tente procurar se "hi" e "ei" tem a mesma origem.  Não é a falta de uma resposta que indica a possibilidade e sim a presença de uma.

Comment: "...E que a pergunta do uai não demonstra pesquisa prévia e pode ser facilmente respondida mediante consulta a um dicionário."   Sim, um dicionário etimológico, é claro.

Comment: "o único estudo minimamente sério trazido à nossa atenção sobre a origem de uai — esta tese de mestrado..."  a qual conclui que: o. Outra tarefa deixada **em aberto** diz respeito à investigação da **hipótese de empréstimo.** (empréstimo linguístico

Comment: "até agora o Centaurus não nos indicou nenhum dicionário que responda à pergunta."    Não fiz porque não tive tempo para fazê-lo.  Tratando-se de algo tão fácil de fazer, qualquer um poderia ter feito.  Mas aqui vai.  Origem de "why" no Oxford Dictionary Online. [Old English hwī, hwȳ ‘by what cause’, instrumental case of hwæt ‘what’, of Germanic origin.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/why)

Comment: Origem do "uai" [Presença inglesa em Minas Gerais?Quando?Onde? Mesmo que houvesse (suponhamos, na criação da malha ferroviária do interior), essa presença seria tão influente assim?O que move a “teoria” desse leitor é a semelhança fonética. Isso é o mesmo que nada. Com base em duas ou três palavras é possível que imaginemos que qualquer língua do planeta tenha influência sobre outra](http://www.recantodasletras.com.br/humor/3790744)   
Mário Eduardo Viaro, Prof de Linguística e Etimologia da USP https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Por_tr%C3%A1s_das_palavras.html?hl=pt-BR&id=sq4C403IwWIC

Comment: Por trás das palavras: manual de etimologia do português.  Prof. Mario Eduardo Viaro.

Comment: Bem, paro por aqui.  Não vou procurar falhas nas tuas perguntas e respostas, como fizeste (certamente existem).  Seria uma atitude infantil e não estamos aqui para isso. Continuo te respeitando como o grande contribuindo do site que és, sempre pronto a oferecer respostas brilhantes.

Comment: Não pretendo levar adiante a discussão.

Comment: Apesar de ter achado a resposta um pouco pessoalizada, dei +1 por ter respondido sobre a parte inicial, que acho importante.

Comment: @Centaurus Editei a minha resposta para atender a algumas das tuas objeções e tornar mais clara a minha posição. Uma preocupação minha é não nos desviarmos demasiado dos critérios seguidos no passado. Daí a referência a perguntas sem pesquisa prévia já existentes. E não tive que as procurar agora. Tenho várias na memória porque me chamaram a atenção na altura em que foram postadas; não votei para as fechar, nem sequer dei voto negativo, porque percebi que eram aceites, e muitas vezes bem recebidas pela comunidade.

Comment: @eightShirt Obrigado pelo voto. Estive a clarificar a resposta. A questão do título, só por si, seria uma duplicata de outras que eu refiro no 1º parágrafo. A razão de ser deste thread é mesmo a pergunta do *uai*. Daí isto ficar um bocado pessoal. Por vezes temos estas discussões no meta sobre perguntas específicas. Dois exemplos em que eu estive envolvido: [esta, que foi fechadda,](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/200/is-this-question-too-broad) e mais [esta, que foi fechada e reaberta.](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/182/is-this-question-a-duplicate)

Comment: @Jacinto obrigado. Eu não costumo frequentar o meta, talvez por isso não as conhecia, então os links fornecidos ajudaram.

Comment: @Jorge B  Quanto a teu comentário... "Eu já te dei o exemplo do "eu vou ir" que também é feita de boatos como essa.", não preciso pesquisar no Google se o que dizes é verdade ou não, se o boato existe ou não. Como membro antigo do SE em Português que tu és, e como moderador, tuas afirmações nunca foram levianas.  Não vivo em Portugal, portanto aceito sem questionar aquilo que tu me dizes em relação a pt-PT.  Pena a recíproca não ser verdadeira quando faço afirmações sobre o que é ou não é verdade em relação a pt-BR. Não discuto gramática a fundo porque não sou formado em língua portuguesa.

Comment: Mas, fora isso, já vivi o suficiente como falante de pt-BR para saber o que digo e não fazer afirmações levianas.  Minha insistência não é pelo fato de concordarem ou não com o meu "closevote" à pergunta do "uai".  Mas sim por tentarem descaracterizar meus argumentos de que se trata de uma falácia e não aceitarem a minha afirmação de que a possível relação entre "why" e "uai" é considerada uma falácia pela maioria dos brasileiros bem letrados, e considerada ridícula.

Answer (score 2):

Olha, eu acho que etimologia "popular" é um bom inimigo a derrotar. E se não pudermos responder aqui com um sonoro "não" a esse tipo de pergunta, essas crendices se espalharão cada vez mais.

E como não poderemos responder "não" se as perguntas não forem feitas, proponho que elas sejam mantidas.

Ou, em outras palavras... uai not?