# When is a question too trivial?

Tags: discussion

A question asked today, ["Camundongo vs rato!"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/6174/2764), can easily be answered by merely checking the two words in a dictionary -- writing the question probably took longer than finding the answer (though not *writing* it).

At the same time, it *is* the kind of question people are likely to google for, and the question quickly attracted various comments, showing an interest that seem to legitimize the post. Besides, the site badly needs a stronger flow of questions, so maybe we shouldn't be too picky.

In this case, actually curious myself about the answer, I let it be and even shared what I found. But, in general, shouldn't we curb such "trivial" questions?

**Edit**: Apparently I didn't search well when I posted this question. Now I found that this subject has already been discussed here:
[Question without prior research](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/60/2764)
[Sobre questões superficiais](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22/2764)
[Estamos abertos a qualquer tipo de pergunta que verse sobre a língua portuguesa?](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/276/2764)
and the community seems to be rather inclined to the openness advocated by [Jorge B.](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/users/153/) in his [answer](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/324/2764).

But we can still use the votes here to gauge the opinions on the issue and see if anything changed in these 3+ years.

Comment: I just saw another example of such a question: [A diferença entre pasto e campo?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/6176/2764).

Comment: In my opinion no question is too trivial to be in this site. If the question is on-topic and as interest to the community then is a good question to be here. Sometimes I'm searching in a dictionary and I have some doubts reading the word meaning. Like this question [Qual é a diferença entre «símbolo» e «emblema»?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/6012/153). If you search "vs" at main site you can find a lot of questions like this.

Comment: @JorgeB. I think yours is a fair position, and it would make a good answer. I'm not so certain - and that's why I proposed the discussion, because of my experience in other sites, where we close any questions whose answers can be found with a quick googling or briefly checking the obvious sources. I'm very open to it being different for different subjects.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion no question is too trivial to be in this site. If the question **is on-topic** and as interest to the community then is a good question to be here. Sometimes I'm searching in a dictionary and I have some doubts reading the word meaning. Like this question [Qual é a diferença entre «símbolo» e «emblema»?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/6012/153). If you search "vs" at main site you can find a lot of questions like this.

I have some experience from [Stackoverflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/). There we open the on-topic questions scope because we don't have good sources in portuguese where we can find the obvious answers. Here we can do the same thing, but if the question is too obvious like «Qual o significado da palavra "comer"?» we have to close as you can see at [Help Center](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> (...)
> Questions about the following topics are welcomed here:
>
> - Portuguese linguistics, orthography, or etymology
> - Usage, grammar, and pronunciation, including dialect differences
> - **The meaning of a word or expression in context (if it is not clear from the dictionary definition)**
> - Problems encountered by people learning Portuguese
>
> (...)
>
> #### What is the meaning of this word?
>
> We do ask that you look up the meaning of words or expressions in a
> dictionary first. If you can't find the answer you're looking for, go
> ahead and ask, but do provide the context in which you found the word
> or expression, and tell us why you find the dictionary answer
> unsatisfactory.

Comment: The comparison with the Stackoverflow em Português is very pertinent. The criterion "not clear from the dictionary" is obviously subjective, but it should be so and we have reasons for preferring to err on the openness.